# What does "Cleans the place out" in bank robbery context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Pulp Fiction (1994)*, Pumpkin says to Honey Bunny:

> Pumpkin: Heard about this one bloke, he walks into a bank with a
> portable phone. He gives the phone to a teller. The bloke on the other
> end says, "We got this guy's  little girl. If you don't give him all
> your money, we're gonna kill her." Knucklehead walks into a bank with
> a telephone. Not a pistol, not a shotgun, a fuckin' phone. **Cleans the
> place out**.

What does "Cleans the place out" in bank robbery context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialogue has someone describing a successful robbery. It means that he got all their money, or at least a lot of it.